# How strong is a Spartan?

Tags: halo

In the Halo universe it has never been clear to me how strong a SPARTAN-II truly is, going from not killing a human by punching it in game, to flipping a 66 ton tank, or simply having gun recoil, so, how strong is a Spartan lore-wise?

Comment: With or without the Mjolnir armor?  I presume with, however their physical enhancements provide them with greater strength even without the Mjolnir armor.

Comment: It's a known fact that a SPARTAN-IV in GEN2 Mjolnir can go toe-to-toe with a SPARTAN-II in GEN1 Mjolnir, because the GEN2 armour is more advanced. Without armour, however, SPARTAN-IIs are far more deadly, and god help anybody who has to deal with a SPARTAN-II wearing GEN2 armour.

Comment: Man.. not a Halo fan but Spartans in Mjolnir armor?  Mix myths much?

Comment: @Paul Well, they needed names for both incredibly well-trained and bred soldiers, and for immense & unstoppable weapons for them to use (anyone claiming that Mjolnir armor isn't a weapon is wrong).

Answer (score 2):

I can't manage to find numerical data trustworthy enough to do precise calculations.

Anyway, the soldiers involved in the SPARTAN-II program were originally 75 children selected based on genetic predispositions. A genetic enhancement process was then conducted on them, increasing their physical and mental abilities even more. The 35 of them who survived the program were given Mjolnir armors, which provide an additional mechanical increase in strength.

To sum it up, the 5 remaining post-war remaining SPARTAN-II are stronger than usual people that were genetically modified and intensively trained during most of their childhood and teen years before being stuck in assisted armors.

**So they are as strong as can a GMO ubersoldier with robot limbs can get.**

Numerical data is more than welcome, even though I consider the canon fact that a SPARTAN-II can single-handedly flip a Warthog as relevant enough.

Comment: I think part of the confusion comes from the fact that they **can** flip jeeps and tanks, yet they also have to deal with weapon recoil. You'd think someone strong enough to heave-ho combat vehicles like MC does that they wouldn't have any issue holding a gun steady while shooting.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I'm not convinced. Of course arm strength must help to absorb recoil, but that's about it. The recoil is a nearly instantaneous blow of kinetic energy that comes from the gun.The SPARTAN-II we play in the game feels the recoil. He isn't thrown away, he just feels it, it messes with his accuracy and that's about it. Besides, handling recoil is more about compensating that blow of kinetic energy thatn about being basically strong... And the game would have been quite dull if we couldn't have any recoil, anyway.

Comment: Your last point is the only one I agree with. I find it hard to believe that they give the guy a suit that can flip tanks but didn't think to provide any recoil dampeners.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Yeah, I tried really hard to wrap my head around it, but in the end I guess a FPS without recoil would be kind of dull.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowD Reaction time maybe? Spartans can't react in time to perfectly counter the recoil, and tensing up beforehand would cause the arm itself to shiver from competing muscles, as well as making them otherwise immobile. Not to mention that if you're slightly off in regards to how you expect the recoil to go, you're gonna face recoil anyways. Flipping a tank is "slow" in comparison, and you only have to apply force in a general direction.

Comment: @Spoki0 You're referring the the **person's** ability to fight recoil. I'm talking about the **suit's**. I doubt that the person in the armor is the one actually flipping all the vehicles. I'm pretty sure *every* action is suit-assisted. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Yes, and the same can apply to the suit. Just substitute reaction time with compute time. Is there any information on the compute power of the suit? It's also not one gun mounted to the suit, but any gun (including unknown alien guns) held by the person, so adding recoil dampeners is really that easy.

Comment: @Spoki0 I'm glad you agree

Comment: isn't really that easy*

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't assume any subsequent standard for Spartan strength however using a comparison sake; Champion squat lifters can lift in excess of 1000 pounds with the current real world record at 1,268 pounds. Considering the modifications done to Spartans bodies they can probably lift as much or more with less effort. However their build is considerably average looking, not as heavily built as professional lifters, especially the female Spartans. Never the less, with augmented muscles added to their bodies at childhood and fortified bones, it's safe to say a Spartan can probably bench press well over pounds or more without tearing ligaments or herniating something. John-117 was seen lifting 495 lbs by age 14 after his augmentations.

Comment: That answer could use a quote/screenshot of something, to make it better and more "in line" with the usual way of answering there. For the last sentence, for instance! :)